# Flutter - control camera resolution

Tags: flutter, camera, resolution

Is there a way to "force" phone camera to take a picture with full HD resolution 1920x1080 instead of default 3420x4032 ?

Comment: Have you considered simply resizing the image afterwards?

Comment: Resizing image afterwards is not a solution - I need something fully automatic with no user involvement...

Comment: Have you searched for packages that will resize images programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package, you can set the resolution using `ResolutionPreset`, see possible values [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/camera_platform_interface/latest/camera_platform_interface/ResolutionPreset.html).

In your case define a `CameraController` after getting available cameras like this (assuming there is a camera available and you want to use the first one):

```
final cameras = await availableCameras();
final controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.veryHigh);
final preview = CameraPreview(controller);
```

This is a simple example, in a real world app you need to keep track of the controller and dispose it properly.